How can I model with random effect on the coefficient
The simple linear regression model is : $$y= a x + b + e $$
However, in real data:

there is random effect (error or variation);
when $x$ increases, the abs of random effect increase proportionally.
So it will look like $$y = ax + b + ex$$ or $$y = (a + e) x + b$$ But the $e$ is random effect.
Any suggestions for this modeling?


Your models look algebraically identical: maybe there's a typo and the first should be $y=ax + b + e$?  If so, the first is ordinary regression and the second is weighted regression: search our site for weighted least squares.

Maybe you're looking at generalized least squares, e.g. implemented in R via gls() in the nlme package with something like weights = varPower(form  = ~fitted(.), fixed = 1) ?

Many thanks whuber and Ben! Good to know and will check !
